# How to write SQL subqueries with count?

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I'm using mysql. I want to count the minimum, maximum, and average number of different tags per movie from one table.

Exclude the duplicate:

- same tag given by the same user to the same movie
- same tag given by different users to the same movie

Example: table 'tags'

| userId | movieId | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | crime |
| 1 | 2 | dark |
| 1 | 2 | dark |
| 2 | 2 | greed |
| 2 | 2 | dark |
| 3 | 3 | music |
| 3 | 3 | dance |
| 3 | 3 | quirky |
| 4 | 3 | dance |
| 4 | 3 | quirky |

Expect result:

| movieId | Min_Tag | Max_Tag | Avg_Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0.66... |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 0.6 |

---

I try to write query like below, but it shows an error.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT movieId, 
  MIN(COUNT(DISTINCT tag) AS Min_Tag,
  MAX(COUNT(DISTINCT tag) AS Max_Tag,
  AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT tag) AS Avg_Tag,
FROM (
  SELECT userId,movieId,tag 
  FROM tags
  GROUP BY userId, movieId, tag
) AS non_dup
GROUP BY movieId;
```

Comment: Please include the error message in the question.

Comment: It seems like you are missing some parenthesis like: `MIN(COUNT(DISTINCT tag))` also if you want to movie-wise counts you need to remove `userId` from the group by statement.

Comment: what's your db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite your query

First you need the count per tag and movie

and fromm that you can calculate min max and avg

```
SELECT
   movieId,
   MIN(count_tag) AS Min_Tag,
  MAX(count_tag) AS Max_Tag,
  AVG(count_tag) AS Avg_Tag
FROM  
(SELECT movieId,tag, count(*) count_tag
  FROM tags
  GROUP BY movieId, tag) non_dup
GROUP BY movieId
```

| movieId | Min_Tag | Max_Tag | Avg_Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1.0000 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2.0000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1.6667 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2JXaXP75)